# How we can open instagram app while login integration in android

Tags: android, authentication, instagram, instagram-api

I'm facing one problem.I need to login with instagram and i have followed method and it work fine but I need to login time it show in dialog or redirect to browser because instagram provide us api's **(api.instagram)** like this  for its authentication.

But i want to know is there any way to login with instragram like facebook integration or and any other.
can we fetch user userinfo from app ? If app is not installed then application redirect to browser otherwise it redirect to app for get user info for login.

anybody any have idea about this, please read patiently and give me answer.I'll appreciate your answer thanks

Comment: this is the way the API is designed by Instagram. I dont think you can do anything about it at this point. lets hope that Instagram updates the API

Comment: ok i understand but is there any way to login with instagram without its api's ?

Comment: hI @aNDROIDTEAM please check the below url

http://siteoftutorials.com/instagram-api-android-tutorial/

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/instagram-integration-android-application-tutorial
Only you need to  change is callbackurl,baseurl and client id

Comment: Thru instagram official application ("com.instagram.android") login to your application is impossible. 
If you try to launch intent with url like this

"https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID_IS_HERE&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL_IS_HERE&response_type=token"

It always redirects you to the default browser.